# Can't Open cbr file on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, rar

Whenever i try to open cbr file with a cbr reader (currently installed software is **comix**). It gives me error message.

> You nedd either the rar or the unrar program installed in order to
>   read RAR (.cbr) files

I have installed **Xarchiver** but still getting the same error. What can i do

Comment: Did you either install rar or unrar as the message suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Cbr file format is indeed used for comix (comic ebooks). Try using Calibre for that. To install Calibre use Gnome Software or just open a Terminal window and type:

> sudo apt-get install calibre

Just remember you have to add that comix to Calibre library first, and then attempt to open it with Calibre Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

Install `unrar`:

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Calibre can't open cbr in 16.04. Try installing YACReader, it was my solution to open all my cbr's files. - http://www.yacreader.com/